# I am getting an illegal start of expression

Tags: java, japplet

```
package einstein;
import javax.swing.JApplet; 
import java.awt.*;
```

starting an applett

```
public class Einstein extends JApplet 
{
//--------------------------------------------------------|
//draws a quotation from albert einstein among some shapes|
//--------------------------------------------------------|
@Override
public void paint (Graphics page)
{
```

illegal start of expression in next line

```
    page.drawRect (50, 50, 40, 40,); //square
    page.drawRect (60, 80, 225, 30); //rectangle
    page.drawOval (75, 65, 20, 20); //circle
    page.drawLine (35, 60, 100, 120); //line

    page.drawString ("Out of clutter, find simplicity.", 110, 70);
    page.drawString ("-- Albert Einstein", 130, 100);

    }
}
```

it originally had a problem with the paint (Graphics page) but apparently the @overide fixed that

Comment: This doesn't really look like `javascript`. Did you mean to tag it as `java`?

Comment: There is a `,` too much in the arguments list...

Answer (score 0):

Ben just remove the extra comma you have typed right after the fourth value you have passed for page.drawRect (50, 50, 40, 40,);//Remove the comma :)

Your final code should be this if you want to see your applet :

```
import javax.swing.JApplet; 
import java.awt.*;

public class Einstein extends JApplet 
{
//--------------------------------------------------------|
//draws a quotation from albert einstein among some shapes|
//--------------------------------------------------------|
@Override
public void paint (Graphics page)
{   
    page.drawRect (50, 50, 40, 40); //square
    page.drawRect (60, 80, 225, 30); //rectangle
    page.drawOval (75, 65, 20, 20); //circle
    page.drawLine (35, 60, 100, 120); //line

    page.drawString ("Out of clutter, find simplicity.", 110, 70);
    page.drawString ("-- Albert Einstein", 130, 100);

    }
}

/*<APPLET CODE="Einstein.java" HEIGHT = 400 WIDTH = 400></APPLET>*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 page.drawRect (50, 50, 40, 40,); // remove extra ,
```

use as follows

```
page.drawRect (50, 50, 40, 40);
```

This is not a serious question, next time check your code twice before come to here. Also i suggest you to use IDE to coding since it will guide you to sorted out this kind of issues.